# What data types does IndexedDb support?

Tags: javascript, nosql, indexeddb

I have searched, but can't seem to find anything about the data types that IndexedDB supports. I know that it supports basic Javascript objects, but what if I want to store an instance of an object or a blob of data? Does IndexedDB support anything more than simple objects or does it have data types to assist in doing creative things?

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IndexedDB use [Structured Cloning Algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm) to serialize the data. Basically it can save all javascript data types in plain object, in nested or in circular reference.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you!